# How to get wifi mac (BSSID) of router you are connected?

Tags: linux, mac-address

How to get wifi mac (BSSID) of router you are connected under Linux? Networkmanager installed.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Where are all close votes now?

Answer (score 2):

With NetworkManager, `nmcli dev wifi list` should show this. The currently associated AP will be marked with an `*` in the "IN-USE" column:

```
$ nmcli dev wifi list --rescan no
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID    MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
        74:28:4D:E7:D5:D3  Foo     Infra  13    270 Mbit/s  94      ▂▄▆█  WPA2
*       74:28:4D:E7:D5:D4  Foo     Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
        0C:A0:E4:24:CD:BF  Foo     Infra  64    270 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
        0C:A0:E4:24:CD:BA  Bar     Infra  8     270 Mbit/s  75      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
```

In older versions:

```
$ nmcli -f in-use,bssid,ssid dev wifi list
```

For WLAN interfaces with modern (nl80211) drivers, run `iw wlan0 link` to see the physical layer information (including BSSID and current rates); `iw wlan0 station dump` might show a little more.

```
$ iw wlan0 link
Connected to 74:28:4d:e7:d5:d4 (on wlan0)
    SSID: Foo
    freq: 5180
    RX: 50127687 bytes (20957 packets)
    TX: 2927390 bytes (8599 packets)
    signal: -53 dBm
    rx bitrate: 433.3 MBit/s VHT-MCS 9 80MHz short GI VHT-NSS 1
    tx bitrate: 468.0 MBit/s VHT-MCS 5 80MHz VHT-NSS 2
```

For WLAN interfaces with old (WEXT) drivers, run `iwconfig wlan0`:

```
$ iwconfig rtl0
rtl0      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Foo"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 06:BF:92:DE:24:DD
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
```

---

*Note: Don't confuse the access-point BSSID with the gateway (router) MAC address. Even if the Wi-Fi AP *is* your router, it might still have a different Wi-Fi BSSID than the link-layer MAC address (e.g. the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks often have slightly different BSSIDs) – and of course on multi-AP networks (whether home mesh, or enterprise) they will be entirely different devices.*

Answer (score -1):

For macOS you can do the following

```
sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
```